# 'redux-saga' not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, redux-saga

I'm trying (learning) to make an asynchronous post request using redux-saga, but i'm getting a synchronous behavior.

this is the code i'm using:

```
import {AUTH_REQUEST} from '../constants/authentication';
import {authSuccess, authError} from '../actions/login';
import {takeEvery, call, put, fork, all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';

const authenticate = (username, password) => {
    axios
        .post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/', {username, password})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('RESPONSE: ', response.data);
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
        });
};

function* watchAuthRequest({username, password, resolve, reject}) {
    try {
        const result = yield call(authenticate, username, password);
        console.log('RESULT', result);
        yield put(authSuccess(result));
        yield call(resolve);
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(authError(error));
        yield call(reject, {serverError: 'Something bad happend !'});
    }
}

const authSaga = function* authSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(AUTH_REQUEST, watchAuthRequest);
};

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(authSaga),
    ]);
};
```

and when i submit the form (i'm using redux-form), this is why i get in my console logs:

```
RESULT: undefined
RESPONSE:  Object {user: Object, token: "04a06266803c826ac3af3ffb65e0762ce909b07b2373c83b5a25f24611675e00"}
```

and even the `authSuccess` action is getting dispatched with an empty payload (`result`)

am i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `return`:

```
const authenticate = (username, password) => {
    return axios
        .post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/', {username, password})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('RESPONSE: ', response.data);
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
        });
};
```

Comment: you won't believe the hours i spent debugging this, yes this is what i was missing. thanks